# In Memory Query to datatable error

Tags: vb.net, datatable, in-memory-tables

I am trying to do something I thought was simple.

I have a list called loc.  I then have code

```
dim locdt = nothing
locdt = EML_StaffingDataSet.TSTAFFRSTR.Select.Where(Function(x As DataRow) loc.Contains(x.Item("rstr_location"))).Distinct
```

That works fine, but when i try to make locdt the datasource for a control, i get a null error, "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid."  Some of the rstr_locations are null, so in the code above how do I remove nulls from the select.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
locdt = EML_StaffingDataSet.TSTAFFRSTR.Select("rstr_location is not null").Where(Function(x As DataRow) loc.Contains(x.Item("rstr_location"))).Distinct
```

How can i convert this to a datatable now so that i can query to return just the rstr_location